# Threading in python on a raspberry pi issues

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a GUI that spawns threads that perform very basic and not computationally complicated tasks on a raspberry pi 1 and I cannot seem to get the threads to work.

I developed the code on a x86 intel computer and it works perfectly well. The threading commands basically just allow for button presses and listening for serial data concurrently.

```
    def extra_thread_disable():
    # Disables buttons that would interfere with data that is currently being sent
    while threading.active_count() == 3:
        run_file_butt.config(state = 'disabled')
        run_butt.config(state = 'disabled')
        serial_butt.config(state = 'disabled')
        popup_butt.config(state = 'disabled')
        homing_butt.config(state = 'disabled')
        level_butt.config(state = 'disabled')
        zero_button1.config(state = 'disabled')
        zero_button2.config(state = 'disabled')
        zero_button3.config(state = 'disabled')
    else:
        run_file_butt.config(state = 'normal')
        run_butt.config(state = 'normal')
        serial_butt.config(state = 'normal')
        popup_butt.config(state = 'normal')
        homing_butt.config(state = 'normal')
        level_butt.config(state = 'normal')
        zero_button1.config(state = 'normal')
        zero_button2.config(state = 'normal')
        zero_button3.config(state = 'normal')
    pass



def thread_data():
    # Starts a thread to send data while allowing stop button to be pressed
    try:
        global t2
        t2 = threading.Thread(name='send_line', target = send_data, daemon = True)
        t_disable = threading.Thread(name='disable', target = extra_thread_disable, daemon = True)
        t2.start()
        t_disable.start()
    except:
        update_textbox("Threading Error: data thread not properly created")



def send_data():
    # Sends single motion commands and waits for response to continue
    global save_path
    global motor_param
    vals = get_vals()
    try:
        data = struct.pack("!llllhhhhhhhh", vals['dist1'], vals['dist2'], vals['dist34'], vals['dist34'], vals['speed1'], vals['speed2'], vals['speed34'], vals['speed34'], vals['accel1'], vals['accel2'], vals['accel34'], vals['accel34'])
        try:
            ser.write(data)
            update_textbox("Running...")
        except:
            update_textbox("Error: Data not sent")
        try:
            motor1pos = int(ser.readline())
            motor2pos = int(ser.readline())
            motor3pos = int(ser.readline())
            motor4pos = int(ser.readline())
            ready = ser.read(1)
            update_textbox("Movement complete")
            axis1_current.set(str(reverse_convert(motor1pos, 1)))
            axis2_current.set(str(reverse_convert(motor2pos, 2)))
            axis3_current.set(str(reverse_convert(motor3pos, 3)))
            writetofile()
        except:
            update_textbox("Error: reading data improperly")
    except:
        update_textbox("Error: data not sent properly")
    pass
```

The code basically just allows the main GUI thread to allow for a stop button to be pressed and disable all the buttons that could interfere with the sent data. That thread then just waits for the response from an arduino it is connected to. Again this all works flawlessly on a normal computer. I get no errors or warnings in the terminal when run on a raspberry pi but it seems to be blocking. I thought maybe it was just such a slow computer or the infamous GIL. It seems like that might be the reason. If so, should I switch to the multiprocessing library in python? is there a way to get around this? It doesn't work when run in terminal calling python3 and it doesn't work when it was compiled to a static binary using pyinstaller.

Comment: There really isn't enough data provided to try to figure out what may be causing the problem. Remember `threading` is for concurrency, `multiprocessing` for parallelism.

Comment: Well I guess what I don't understand is why the program performs vastly different actions on the different hardware even though the python interpreter would keep in consistent for them. Is it just something that can't be done on a pi? It just isn't threading but I get no errors either

Comment: Testing on windows then taking it to a raspberry pi?

Comment: Nope, arch linux. well manjaro. And the other thing is the data is sent, The button call on the GUI calls the threading function which then sends the data so the thread would have to be started. It just takes over control of all threads it seems

Comment: Same serial connection? I have a feeling this might be more a change of hardware, or change of library issue, than it is a threading vs multiprocessing issue.

Comment: Im using the right port cause my arduino makes the things move when the data is sent so it has to be connected properly via serial. And it was a problem when I used pyinstaller to make an executable. I had to redo pyinstaller on a raspi to get it to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to get better hardware. I changed nothing in my code but instead bought a newer raspberry pi 4 instead of the original raspberry pi and the threading worked as it originally did on my other pc running arch.